# installing from setup.py but ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I was trying to make a python package. This is my package structure.

```
my-package  
├── README.md  
├── LICENSE  
├── .gitignore  
├── setup.py  
└── my-package  
    ├── __init__.py
    └── other_files.py
```

in my `setup.py`:

```
import io
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, find_namespace_packages

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="new-package",    # This is the name of the package
    version="1.0.0",      # The initial release version
    author="Author Name", # Full name of the author
    author_email='author@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/Author/myPackage',
    description="Short Descriptio",
    long_description=long_description,      # Long description read from the the readme file
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=find_namespace_packages(),    # List of all python modules to be installed
    classifiers=[
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Internationalization',
    ],                                      # Information to filter the project on PyPi website
    python_requires='>=3.5',                # Minimum version requirement of the package
    install_requires=['requests','simplejson'],  # Install other dependencies if any
)
```

from the root directory, I am generating distribution files using this command:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Then, I am installing this package in a virtualenvironment using this command, from the package root directory:

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

After installing, if I run `pip list`, it shows me that this package (`new_package`) is installed.

but when I try to import this, using `import new_package`, it gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new_package'
```

I have searched in the stack for similar problem, but could not solve it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

try to rename the inner `my-package` folder to `my_package` as hyphen is not a valide name for **packages** or **modules** to import

```
my-package  # root folder
├── README.md  
├── LICENSE  
├── .gitignore  
├── setup.py  
└── my_package  # HERE, this package   
    ├── __init__.py
    └── other_files.py
```

and rebuild and reinstall the distribution

Note: the name of root folder `my-package` doesn't matter if it contains a hyphen because it's meant for publishing on `pypi` repository and for `pip` command to install the package